# how can I find and print the content of an attribute by a given number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

So the program works like this, i need to input a number and once my program identifies the number in the class it will print the given number in LCD format ([7-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display)).

```
class lcd:
  def numbers():
    0 = ["_","| |","_"]
    1 = ["|","|","|"]
    2 = ["_","_|","|_"]
    3 = ["_","_|","_|"]
    4 = ["|_|"," |"]
    5 = ["_","|_"," _|"]
    6 = ["_","|_","|_|"]
    7 = ["_"," |"," |"]
    8 = ["_","|_|","|_|"]
    9 = ["  _","|_|"," _|"]

def numgen(num):
  print("Type the number you want to print in LCD: ")
  num = lcd()
  for i in range (lcd):
    if hasattr(num,'numbers'):
      for i in range (3):
        print("\n")
 return  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  num = int(input())
  numgen()
  print(num)
```

The problem is that I don't know how can I proceed, i've been reading some functions but none of them works. I tried as you can see a weird way with hasattr but obviously it didn't work.  In the last loop I tried to print that space for each object in my attributes, so in that way the number will print correctly.
I will much appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't assign a new value to int literals. It is not clear what you even expect the `numbers` function to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This seems like an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? Do you know how to use [lists](//docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)? Please read [ask]. If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: Honestly, the code is totally incomprehensible. 1) like @khelwood said, there's a syntax error. 2) `numgen()` requires an argument but you don't give it one. 3) `range(lcd)` won't work because it's not convertable to an integer, and why would it be? 4) It never attempts to actually get an attribute. 5) Even if `0 = ` weren't a syntax error, it'd be local to `numbers`, so how would you get it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to print numbers in LCD format (or rather 7 segments).

Here is a minimal code for it. The most important part is to use `zip` to build the lines.

NB. I had to fix your digit segments that were incorrect.

```
digits = {
    0 : [" _ ","| |","|_|"],
    1 : [" ","|","|"],
    2 : [" _ "," _|","|_ "],
    3 : ["_ ","_|","_|"],
    4 : ["   ", "|_|","  |"],
    5 : [" _ ","|_ "," _|"],
    6 : [" _ ","|_ ","|_|"],
    7 : ["_ "," |"," |"],
    8 : [" _ ","|_|","|_|"],
    9 : [" _ ","|_|"," _|"],}

def print_num(num):
    parts = [digits[int(d)] for d in str(num)]
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in zip(*parts)))
    
print_num(1234567890)
```

Output:

```
   _  _       _   _  _   _   _   _ 
|  _| _| |_| |_  |_   | |_| |_| | |
| |_  _|   |  _| |_|  | |_|  _| |_|
```